# What Docker command can I use after login to Docker registry?

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I am new to Docker. I know the default registry is 'docker hub'. And there are tutorials on navigating 'Docker Hub', e.g. search image etc. But that kind of operations are performed in Docker Hub UI via web.

I was granted a private Docker registry. After I login using the command like `docker login someremotehost:8080`, I do not know what command to use to navigate around inside the registry. I do not know what images are available and what their tags are.

Could anyone share some info/link on what command to use to explore **private remote registry** after user login?

Also, to use images from the private registry, the name I need to use becomes something like `'my.registry.address:port/repositoryname`.

Is there a way to change the configuration of my docker application, so that it will make my.registry the default registry, and I can just use `repositoryname`, without specifying registry name in every docker command?

Comment: Take a look at this part of documentation https://docs.docker.com/storage/ Especially  "tmpfs mounts". Does it what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no standard CLI commands to interact with remote registries beyond `docker pull` and `docker push`.  The registry itself might provide some sort of UI (for example, Amazon ECR can list images through the standard AWS console), or your local development team might have a wiki that lists out what's generally available.

You can't change the default Docker registry.  You have a pretty strong expectation that *e.g.* `ubuntu` is really `docker.io/library/ubuntu` and not something else.

Answer (score 0):

For the Docker there are only two commands for communication of registry:

```
Docker Pull and Docker Push
```

And about the docker private registry there is no any default setting in docker to get the pull from only from the specific registry. The reason for this is name of docker image.For official docker image there is direct name like `Centos` . But in the docker registry there is also some images which is created by non-official organisation or person. In that kind of docker images there is always name of user or organisation like `pivotaldata/centos`. So this naming convention is help to docker find the image in docker registry in public(via login) or public registry.
In the case you want to interact more with private repo you can write your own batch script or bash script. Like I have created a batch script which pull all the tag from the private repo if user give the wrong tag.

```
@echo off

docker login --username=xxxx --password=xxxx
docker pull %1:%2

IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL%==0 (
echo "Specified Version is Not Found "
echo "Available Version for this image is :"
for /f %%i in (' curl -s -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X POST -d "{\"username\":\"user\",\"password\":\"password\"}" https://hub.docker.com/v2/users/login ^|jq -r .token ') do set TOKEN=%%i
curl -sH "Authorization: JWT %TOKEN%" "https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/%1/tags/" | jq .results[].name
)
```